# Python's equivalent of "EQUIVALENCE" concept in Fortran?

Tags: python, porting, equivalence

I am interested in rewriting an old Fortran code to Python. The code was for solving any general field variable, call it `F` (velocity, temperature, pressure, etc). But to solve each variable we have to define `EQUIVALENCE` of that variable to `F`.

For example, something like this:

```
EQUIVALENCE (F(1,1,1),TP(1,1)),(FOLD(1,1,1),TPOLD(1,1))
```

Is there a Python version of the above concept?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to manipulate the memory usage in python.
You can perhaps simply use a list.

```
F=[]
```

and

```
FOLD=[]
```

When you do

```
F=FOLD
```

F and FOLD will point to the same data. 
I would suggest to use numpy and scipy to create solvers and use python concepts to make it efficient instead of trying to mimic fortran concepts. Especially very old ones.

Comment: (I don't understand the Python concept mentioned here, but a quick comment:) The Fortran `equivalence` statement of the question doesn't necessarily make `F` and `TP` "point" to the same data.  Instead it makes (part of) `T` and (part of) `TP` point to the same thing.  That is, the two arrays may be of different lengths and it'll be only the _overlap_ that share memory.  Does this Python construct of the answer have the same effect?

Comment: No it doesn't it moves the pointer (so to speak) from one list to the other.

Comment: @Michael, I won't be equating `F` and `FOLD`. Instead, I have to equate `F` to `T` and `FOLD` to `TOLD`. 
`F`and `FOLD` has been defined as 3-dimensional arrays. Since there'd be so many variables (velocity, temperature, pressure etc), it's difficult to solve each of them SEPARATELY and hence he has used the idea of `EQUIVALENCE` to solve for each variable as `F(:,:,1) = T`, `F(:,:,2) = v`, `F(:,:,3) = p` etc...

Comment: I think I have to do something similar to above but not exactly based on `EQUIVALENCE`. Maybe something like `F(:,:,1) = T`, `F(:,:,2) = v`, `F(:,:,3) = p`. And then solve for them all in a loop with loop index as 3rd dimension of the array `F`. Can someone tell me if the above approach would be fine or would there be a better way to do this?